# jquery hover and stay until mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I am trying to create a 'cart' link where the shopping cart opens out on hover. I am able to get the cart to open out on hover and close when moving away. However I cannot get the cart block to stay open once hovered over. I would like the car block to open out on hover and stay open if you hover over it. You will see what I mean if you hover over the 'cart' link in the top right corner of this page.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4380589/Rococlothing/index.html

The jQuery I am using is:

```
jQuery('#cart-links .links .first a').mouseover(function(){
  jQuery('.block-cart').slideDown(400);
}).mouseout(function(){
  jQuery('.block-cart').slideUp(400);
});

jQuery(".block-cart").mouseover(function(){
 jQuery(this).show();
}).mouseout(function(){
 jQuery(this).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kongr45gpen/K55ct/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hovered = false;

jQuery('#cart-links .links .first a').mouseover(function(){
    jQuery('.block-cart').slideDown(400);
}).mouseout(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
      if(!hovered) {
        jQuery('.block-cart').slideUp(400);
      }}, 250);
   });

jQuery(".block-cart").mouseover(function(){
 hovered = true;
}).mouseout(function(){
 hovered = false;
 jQuery('#cart-links .links .first a').trigger("mouseout");
});
```

Comment: Actually, I like the solution by @kongr45gpen better. It uses `.mouseleave()`, `.mouseenter()`, and rearranges the HTML so `block-cart` is inside `#cart-links`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I wasnt able to get the cart-block as child html so I opted for 'Detect's reposnse which works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to cancel the first `mouseout()` so you'll need adjust the second part to

```
jQuery(".block-cart").mouseover(function(){
 jQuery(this).stop(true).show();
}).mouseout(function(){
 jQuery(this).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

note that the `stop`, I am passing in true so its clearing the current animation queue. jQuery doc for stop is @ http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `.block-cart` is not a child of the element that triggers the hover, so in order to keep the hover state active you'd have to structure your HTML in a way that the `.block-cart` is a child element of the element that triggers the hover.

Btw: why don't you use `$(this).hover()` instead of `$(this).mouseover().mouseout()`, it's a little easier

Comment: Hello thanks for the help, unfortunately I am having a lot of trouble trying to get the html to be a child of the required element. This is because the website is based on magento cart software and is very difficult to change around. I thought that if there was a way I could delay the mouseout of the hover on the cart-link, I may be able to initialise the hover of the block-cart function therefore the cart wouldn't disappear. Is this possible